# SQL Server - Agent - Execution job with schedule slower

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have a lot of jobs in SQL Agent (version 2012) some are execution procedures and other SSIS execution packages and I created a new job for SSIS packages with scheduling and I saw that when the job execution is automatic through a schedule it takes up to 30s to start the package.

If I run the job manually, that time will be 2s.

Automatic execution:

> Message Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version
> 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  09:29:09  DTExec: The package execution
> returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).  Started:  09:29:09  Finished: 09:29:30
> Elapsed:  20.609 seconds.  The package executed successfully.  The
> step succeeded.

Manual execution:

**[EDIT]**

Right-click on the job: **Start Job at Step...**

This process is running on the database server and the SSIS packages are also from the same server.

[image]

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60
> for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
> Started:  09:31:29  DTExec: The package execution returned
> DTSER_SUCCESS (0).  Started:  09:31:29  Finished: 09:31:32  Elapsed:
> 2.812 seconds.  The package executed successfully.  The step succeeded.

I already deleted and recreated the job again, but the problem continued.

Comment: If you have the package deployed to SSIS catalog, look at the reports of SSIS package execution history and compare the two executions, you will be able to tell which step is taking longer to run during automatic execution. No one on this platform will be able to help you with no access to package or your server.

Comment: My package is in windows files, but the delay is not related to the execution of the package, but when it is executed by a schedule, the delay of up to 30s is divided 90% to start the schedule and 10% to start and end the execution of the package. This occurs with the execution of procedures also

Comment: Well then you should first put your packages in the right place .i.e in the SSIS catalog and it will give you access to the very useful SSIS package execution built-in reports.

Comment: While converting your project to the project deployment model as M.Ali will provide out of the box reporting, you can collect metrics using the native [Event Logging](https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-ssis-package-logging/) You can even get some information as-is by increasing the reporting level from [dtexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-ver15). Add `/rep eiwp` to the package invocation

Comment: When you run the job manually, how do you do that? What computer are you on that launches the process, where do the ssis packages live and where are the associated resources the packages will work with (database, file, etc). How does that differ from the automatic execution?

Comment: The company uses SSIS projects as windows files and this cannot be changed. For other jobs that also use SSIS packages everything works normally, we have more than 210 jobs, each with its own schedule. I don't know if the amount of jobs and schedules may be causing this slowness. I changed the post with more details of manual execution